# Summary Toolbar (different style on same page)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, toolbar

I have 2 list web parts on the same page, both are using 'summary toolbar' type.

However, one web part has this style:

[image]

And another like this:

[image].

It's not a big deal to me but my manager wants them the same...

Is there a way to make them consistent? Same result using Chrome, Edge, and IE.

Comment: What is the list template used for the web part with green sign? Is there any grouping or different table style than default is used in view?

Comment: There is no list grouping and using custom list on both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This **mainly** depends on the current `selected view` and the current `toolbar type`

**In case,**

- The `selected view` is `Summary view`,
- The `toolbar type` is `summary toolbar` or any other type else `No toolbar`

You will get the old `add new`,

[image]

> **Note:** after selecting `Summary view`, `summary toolbar`, you should stop editing the page to get it reflected with the old `add new`
>   link.

**Unfortunately,** when you edit the `list view web part`, you can't specify which view is currently selected, and it shows by default `Current View`

**So,** it's not a good solution to remove the web part and add it again because you don't know which view was selected!

The **recommended workaround** to change the `selected view` to any other view **else** `Summary view`

Answer (score 0):

The new item image with the green plus sign is a SharePoint 2010 or 2007 version. You need to remove the web part and add that again on the page to get new item image with the blue plus sign.